# Uncaught ReferenceError: funcName is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

'm getting annoying error when i try to include js file **"Uncaught ReferenceError: funcName is not defined"**

im working on laravel 4.2 i use php view file to include the js example :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
    <html  lang="he" >
    <head>
    <meta  charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>example</title>
    <script src="/form/js/formJS.js"></script>
```

when it runs on client side and i click on the img myFunc action - returns the error

```
<img id="sig_1" width=100 height=75  alt=""  onclick="myFunc('sig_1_img1');" src= "url"  />
```

**i try to include the script in the main level of the html view and it works. 
 but i don't want to include the file in this level
i want to use this script Only when the specific file uploaded by the command       `include ($pat_to_file)`**

the js function is

```
function myFunc(sig_id)
{
  sigWindow = window.open("/forms_module_files/js/sig.html?sig_id="+sig_id, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=500, left=500, width=550, height=500");
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: where did you define the 'myFunc()' function? in formJS.js?

Comment: yes myFunc() define in formJS.js

Comment: and your 'img' line appear after the '<script... formJS>' line?

Comment: Of course the image is placed in the body of the HTML  and the include placed in the head

Comment: It seems that formJS.js did not load at all

Comment: did you check it in the network tab? (in the chrome developer tool)? are you getting 200 OK ?

Comment: can you add your js code?

Comment: i can't see it load in the devtool->Network->Scripts

Comment: I think it's not a problem in the function because when I try to include the script's in the main level HTML view it works fine, but I do not want to include the file there

Comment: in chrome, press F12, go to the network tab (where you can see all network traffic, like wireshark). now refresh the page with F5 and see if you getting the js file correct

Comment: the js file didn't load

Comment: just remove the slash before the slash. does it help?

Answer (score 1):

You can put reference to the jquery file.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/form/js/formJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have problem with declaring some .js. With this code I can tell you only this. Find what is missing maybe jquery-1.2.6.min.js or something like that.

Comment: i think that formJS.js did not load at all because that i can't see it load in the   devtool->Network->Scripts

Comment: Great you found reason. Now try to declare this js using code in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

can you try to remove the first slash? (before the form directory)

```
<script src="form/js/formJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: if i do it i don't get the path to the file location

Comment: ok, just for the test.. put it in the same directory where the html file is (the one we are talking about) and try to change the line to: <script src="formJS.js"></script>

Comment: i work with laravel so the root is public folder ...the file that i want to load the script in it is a php file and his location is app folder so the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: /form/js/formJS.js is the path from the public folder to the js file

Comment: Is it possible that I am not able to load the JS file in the PHP file  related to the fact that the file opened by the include command ($ pat_to_file) Somehow ?

Comment: try to move the php variable and put hard-coded path like I suggested (without the /) or put the file in the same folder as the html and again hard coded. let's see if it solve first

Comment: did it work? if so, can you mark the answer as solved please?

Comment: Unfortunately, all the attempts to make the js file loading are failed .......... I gave up  for now  and just leave it on the home page :(
Many thanks for the help